# A docker security issue about /dev/random to make DoS attack in the Azure AKS environment

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes

We find a docker security issue to exhaust all entropy of /dev/random in Linux Kernel and causing DoS attack in the Azure AKS environment.

Reproduction steps:

1. Follow the AKS tutorial to set up AKS clusters. We use one Virtual Machine with 8G memory, 120G SSD Disk, linux 5.4.0-1043-azure OS, Kubernetes Version V1.18.14 and Docker Version 19.3.14, to set the Azure Kubernetes Cluster. All those settings are done through by Azure Kubernetes UI.
2. Deploy the docker unprivileged malicious container with UID 1000, dropping all capabilities, using limited memory 2G, running on special core and disable privilege escalation. We run malicious container in a separate Kubernetes Namespace.
3. In the malicious contianer, we start 100 processes and read random data from /dev/random. As a result, the entropy of /dev/random is exhausted, read request from victim container always blocked, it can not get any random data from /dev/random.

   Is there any way to defend against this attack inside Azure AKS environment? Looking forward to your reply!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56077948/how-to-improve-random-number-generation-in-kubernetes-cluster-containers

Comment: Containers share the host kernel and other resources; you can't run truly untrusted code in containers and expect strong isolation.  This seems like more of a question about security controls in a Kubernetes cluster than a programming question; is there application source code this impacts?